# PHP SOAP HEADER Construction (wsse)

Tags: php, soap, header

I need to write the SOAP Header inside PHP as is described in the picture below:

[SOAP Request Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yjM.png)

My first attempt was an array which I would pass to the SoapClient method `__setSoapHeaders()`:

```
array(
    new SoapHeader($namespace, 'UsernameToken', $this->partner->partner_id),
    new SoapHeader($namespace, 'USERNAME', $this->partner->email),
    new SoapHeader($namespace, 'PASSWORD', $this->partner->password)
);
```

The error I keep getting when making the actual `__soapCall()` is:

```
Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: ns1:InvalidSecurity, faultstring: An error was discovered processing the header.)
```

I just seem unable to get it to work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WsSecurity](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/WsSecurity) project and it'll be done within seconds as you'll be able to easily add the SoapHeader to your existing request,

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem I was having. You're a life saver!